# Last part of ternary operator says "1", but $start = 0, do not understand

Tags: php, youtube, ternary-operator

The code below comes from the YouTube webpage https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0tPluz072E. The uploader of the video does a fairly decent job explaining things, but the one thing that I feel he didn't quite explain fully is why the last part of the ternary operator (in other words, the "else" part of the "if" statement) shows "1", whereas in the very next line, you see $start = $page-1. I can understand that in PHP, pages always start with zero, so why not just have "0" in the last part of the ternary operator?

My second question is, you see an "(int)" in the second part (i.e. the part after the condition) of the ternary operator. The uploader very briefly says that this has something to do with "security". I have googled this issue, but nothing that I have found links (int) with anything to do with security. Anyone knows anything about this?

```
<?php

mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "testsite");

$per_page = 6;
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT name FROM users LIMIT 0, 6");
$pages_query = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM users");
$pages = ceil(mysqli_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

while ($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      echo $query_row['name'].'<br />';
}

if ($pages >= 1) {
   for($x = 0; $x >= $pages; $x++) {
      echo '<a href="?page='.x.'">'.x.'</a>';
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: i have yet to see a php you-tube tutorial worth following

Comment: Start by looking again at `COUNT('id')` and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - Plus, you've an important parameter missing. It concerns mysqli_query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and your use of http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: i assume thats an attempt at pagination? there's NO need for 2 queries

Comment: Dagon, yes, it's pagination. I think the first query is to make sure which row you want to start your display at.

Comment: @Dagon they're not using `mysql_`. Just not connecting properly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the tutorial does, i see the OP is not. So he's learning ;-)

Comment: @Dagon ah ok, they thought maybe they could just add an `i` to the functions to make it run like `mysqli_`. but I left them links above on how to use them.

Comment: Yes, apologies for my error. The guy on YouTube was using the deprecated "mysql", whereas what I did was use the presently-used "mysqli" which of course uses the extra parameter Fred mention, which is the connection variable.

Comment: they should of made mysqli backwards compatible - for  the sake of sanity